# sequence with a quadratic form of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrix-equations

I just face to a sequence with a quadratic form of matrices, when I work on discrete Lyapunov equation:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n A^kR_0(A^*)^k = R_0+AR_0A^*+A^2R_0(A^*)^2+...+A^{n-1}R_0(A^*)^{n-1}+A^nR_0(A^*)^n$$
The matrix A is a stable matrix (all its eigenvalues are in the unit disk) and $R_0$ could be an arbitrary matrix (the relaxed version could be the block diagonal case). I did so many searches and didn't find any special answers to these questions:
1) Condition(s) of convergence
2) The amount of limit if the sequence is convergence.

Comment: Do you really mean that the series in the right is finite and is equal to the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is stable then the spectral radius is less than one and the series certainly converges absolutely (it follows from [Gelfand's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand.27s_Formula) which gives estimates on $\|A^n\|$).

Let's calculate
$$
P=\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^kR_0(A^*)^k=R_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^kR_0(A^*)^k=
R_0+A\cdot \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty A^{k-1}R_0(A^*)^{k-1}}_{=P}\cdot A^*.
$$ 
Therefore, the sum $P$ is the solution to the Lyapunov equation
$$
APA^*-P+R_0=0.
$$

Comment: Exactly. I derived the series from the Lyapunov sequence with a small change:
$$P_{k+1}=AP_{k}A^*+R_{k} $$
the $R$ matrices changing through the time steps, and they are all positive definite (they are all covariance matrices). By assumption of equal $R_k$, it is changed to the sequence which I mentioned before. Does the answer to Lyapunov equation bound this series? or is there any other bound or solving for this kind of Lyapunov sequence?
Thank you for your kindness.